# Do I have to physically return a gym to retrieve a pokemon when the gym is defeated?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm thinking about leaving my Vaporeon at the gym near where I work. I know that I might be lucky to keep it there one or two days, but darnit, I wanna do it. So <s>if</s> when the gym falls, do I need to physically return to it to get my pokemon back?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274212/what-happens-to-pok%C3%A9mon-you-leave-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go-gyms

Comment: >:( Not the same question, only related. (After being a good SE'er all the dupes I was asking got me to do a full site search!)

Comment: appreciate you looking, I was just posting it as a related question that might help you out

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No you do not! It returns to you automatically. As of Android version 0.35.0/iOS version 1.50, ousted defenders return to you with 0 HP, per the [patch notes](https://pokemonblog.com/2016/08/25/pokemon-gos-new-update-also-fixes-hp-bug/comment-page-1/).

Comment: The 1hp is if you fight someone on the same team. If the gym gets taken over you're going to need to revive.

Comment: @kriski I don't think that's true. I believe you only need to revive if you attack an enemy gym and lose. If your Pokemon is defeated in your own gym, it is returned with 1 HP.